# iOS Settings.bundle localization difficulties

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, settings.bundle

From what I can read I'm not the only having this problem; except this is just happening in my `Settings.bundle` in my app it's all fine…

My app is localized in English (primary) and French.

My `Root.strings` file isn't getting called in at all, for English and French. If I put my iPhone in French the Settings bundle will be defaulted to the title declared in my `Root.plist`. Now in whatever language my iPhone's set to (English or French), let's say I add a group entitled "hello" and set the corresponding string to "world" I'll just get "hello" as my "localized" string…

Thanks

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396078/how-to-localize-settings-bundle-in-xcode4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been struggling with the same problem. Using version 5.0 of the iOS simulator and Xcode 4.2, the localizations don't appear to take effect when the Root.strings file is changed.

My setup has a Settings.bundle which contains a Root.plist and a directory for each language supported containing a Root.strings file:

```
Settings.bundle:
    Root.plist
    en.lproj:
        Root.strings
    fr.lproj:
        Root.strings
```

This is pretty much the standard setup which Apple documentation suggests.

When simulator is using the english localization, I change the matching Root.strings file and recompile, the changes don't appear to take effect. But if I uninstall the app, clean the project, and then re-run, the localization takes effect. It seems like an Xcode or iOS Simulator bug.

**My solution**: uninstall the app from the simulator, then run it again from Xcode to see the changes.

Comment: when i select different language other than above two languages. eg, if i select dutuch language on device. is it take default language english or not?

Comment: Is it possible to keep default English language ?